# How to stop git update and clear git cache in Windows

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want to stop egit from updating the repository with modifications I make to an app, which I downloaded from git. I found out that I have to update .gitignore file. I did that. But then I read that I have to clear the git cache also. But all the procedures I find are for the linux setup of Eclipse. I don't find any information on how to do this in the Windows environment. On Linux setup, you can issue "git rm -r --cached [filename]", and that stops git from updating the repository with changes to the file. But I can not find the git or egit executable in my setup. I am running Eclipse from the Android bundle setup. This is a zip file that you can download from Android developer site, and it has Eclipse along with Android Development Environment. I am running this on a Windows 7 machine.  I think egit is the Eclipse addon for git? Is that right? 
I found this link: [Eclipse Git Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html) But it did not help me.